# GraphQL: Writing Frontend Query with Optional Arguments

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am currently trying to write a GraphQL Query called **recipe** which can take a number of optional arguments based on a graphQL input called RecipeSearchInput, and uses the input to find a specific recipe matching the attributes passed.

I am struggling to write the frontend query to be able to be able to take the arguments as an object.

Here's my graphQl schema for graphql input RecipeSearchInput.

```js
     input RecipeSearchInput {
  _id: ID
  title: String
  cookTime: Int
  prepTime: Int
  tools: [String!]
  ingredients: [String!]
  steps: [String!]
  videoURL: String
  tags: [String!]
  country: String
}
```

And here's my query written in the frontend to access the my mongodb server through graphql:

```js
// gql query that requests a recipe
export const findOne = obj => {
  let requestBody = {
    query: `
              query {
                recipe(recipeInput: ${obj}) {
                  _id
                  title
                  cookTime
                  prepTime
                  tools
                  ingredients
                  steps
                  videoURL
                  tags
                  country
                }
              }
            `
  };

  return fetchEndpoint(requestBody);
};
```

When I wrote my frontend query with a simple object that I knew existed in my database:

```js
const displayData = async () => {
    const recipeData = await api.recipe.findOne({
      title: "Greek Chicken Skewers"
    });

    console.log(recipeData);
  };
```

This gives me the following error:

```
message: "Expected value of type "RecipeSearchInput", found [object, Object]."
```

The problem I'm seeing is that **obj** is not formatted properly (in String form) to be received by Graphql as an input. The Graphql query params look like this:

[Here is what the working query looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0obI.png)

**What's the best approach for making a query that takes more than one argument?** How should I package up the argument in the frontend to please GraphQL?

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if any of this was unclear!

Shawn

Comment: Find my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660045/graphql-build-query-arguments-from-object/50670656#50670656

Comment: Thanks for the response. This solved my issue.